# ToolStripButton disappear from PropertyGrid when user log-in to Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, user-interface

I have a problem and scenario is the following:

I've created user control with one component `PropertyGrid`. To this `PropertyGrid` I added button (Heximal Mode) to the PropertyGrid's `ToolStrip`. Everything is fine and works great!

But when this control is shown in form and user press `"Windows->Switch User"` and logging again with same User Name my button (Heximal Mode) **disappear**. Also the fourth button which was manually hid appears...

I don't know what happen. Probably windows reload its component on user log-in?
Windows 7 (x64/x86)

```
public partial class CompProperty : UserControl
  {
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton _tsbMode = null;

    public CompProperty()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      createAdditionalButtons();
    }

    private void createAdditionalButtons()
    {
      foreach ( Control control in propertyGrid.Controls )
      {
        ToolStrip toolStrip = control as ToolStrip;

        if ( toolStrip != null )
        {
          toolStrip.Items[4].Visible = false;

          _tsbMode = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
          _tsbMode.CheckOnClick = true;
          _tsbMode.Checked = true;
          _tsbMode.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
          _tsbMode.Image = Resources.img_edit;
          _tsbMode.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
          _tsbMode.Name = "tsbMode";
          _tsbMode.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( 23, 22 );
          _tsbMode.Text = "Heximal Mode";
          _tsbMode.ToolTipText = "Heximal Mode";

          toolStrip.Items.AddRange( new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            _tsbMode} );
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is by design.  The PropertyGrid class rebuilds the toolbar when the SystemEvents.UserPreferencesChange event fires.  Which is indeed likely to fire on a desktop switch.  You could patch it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyPropertyGrid : PropertyGrid {
    protected override void OnSystemColorsChanged(EventArgs e) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Not ideal of course.  Cold hard fact is that this simply isn't supported.